# How do I edit neo4j.conf in an AuraDB instance?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc, neo4j-aura

I am trying to edit the settings of my AuraDB hosted neo4j instance, specifically, trying to set the following line:

```
apoc.import.file.enabled=true
```

I have looked at [the official tutorial](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/neo4j-conf/) and many other places, and for the life of me, I am not able to find out where either the "settings" button is located, or how to locate the  neo4j.conf or apoc.conf files. It seems that something has possibly changed in a newer version. I have tried both in the browser at https://console.neo4j.io/#databases and in Neo4J Desktop. For the desktop application, I am running it on Ubuntu via the .appimage. I created my database on the website and connected via remote connection following [this guide](https://neo4j.com/docs/aura/auradb/getting-started/connect-database/#_neo4j_desktop).

Some things that might help me solve the issue:

- Is it possible to open a shell in auradb to let me run normal bash commands?
- Is the .conf accessible "within" the .appimage?

From the official description of [File locations](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/), I am supposedly able to do the following in Neo4j Desktop to find the configuration file:

> From the Open dropdown menu of your Neo4j instance, select Terminal,
> and navigate to /conf/neo4j.conf.

Yet, when I press the Open dropdown menu, I do not see a Terminal option. What I get is Neo4j Browser, Neo4j Bloom, and Neo4j ETL Tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aura is a managed database - which is to say that you don't get low-level access to configuration of the kind you're describing. The documentation you're looking at relates to self-hosted instances of Neo4j, where you're the one managing and configuring the instance from scratch and where you have that level of access to the underlying configuration.

To the problem you're trying to solve, the following article entitled [Loading data into Neo4j Aura](https://aura.support.neo4j.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500011497162-Loading-Data-into-Neo4j-Aura) is your best bet for the currently available options for loading data into your managed database.

Per [the documentation](https://aura.support.neo4j.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038743233-APOC-stored-Procedures-and-Functions-in-Neo4j-Aura), APOC is installed in Aura databases, but only a limited set of functions and procedures are enabled (as of May 2022). In particular, only a small subset of `apoc.import` procedures are available - from what I can see, CSV and GraphML support is enabled via `apoc.load.csv` and `apoc.load.graphml`, while you also have access to `apoc.load.json` and `apoc.load.xml`.

Lists of the currently supported procedures and functions are available at the foot of that document:

- [Neo4j Aura Supported APOC procedures (updated).json](https://aura.support.neo4j.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/360089598554/Neo4j_Aura_Supported_APOC_procedures__updated_.json)
- [Neo4j Aura Supported APOC functions (updated).json](https://aura.support.neo4j.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/360091756133/Neo4j_Aura_Supported_APOC_functions__updated_.json)

Comment: while apoc.load.csv is available, it only works with links to online files (local file access is disabled and there seems to be no way to currently alter the offending apoc.config)

Answer (score 0):

From a [Neo4j Aura Knowledge Article](https://aura.support.neo4j.com/hc/en-us/articles/360058108053-Can-you-set-any-database-property-that-belongs-to-neo4j-conf-in-Aura-):

> In Aura, we currently do not support changing any property that may
> exist in the Neo4j product and defined in neo4j.conf.